# Using the limit comparison test to find whether a series is divergent or convergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The series is:

[image]

I'm trying to compare it to:

[image]

Which converges when using p-series. However I'm not sure if both converge using the limit comparison test.

Comment: Limit compare with $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**:You compare it with $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^2}$ instead, **or** simply do a little trick: $\sum\dfrac{n+2}{(n+1)^3} = \sum\dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\sum\dfrac{1}{(n+1)^3}$

Comment: Can you please explain why I have to compare it to 1/n^2?

Comment: Basically the top behaves like $n$ and the bottom like $n^3$.